# Selecting variables in Grafana using CSV datasource

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am using a CSV datasource and have created Variables like here, with a list of values:
[image]

I want to reference this in my query and so I use the Transform option like below, but it doesnt work. Any idea how I can do it better or right?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to sort this issue? I'm having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: No alfven. I couldn't.